# why the buffer capacity depends on the ratio of salt and acid in acidic buffer?

Tags: acid-base, ph

According to the Henderson–Hasselbatch equation  when  pH =  Pka for  any  buffer solution then  why  we  say  that  this is  the  best  buffer?

Comment: Related: [Why is Buffer capacity maximum when the ratio of its components is 1?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7611/7951)

Answer (score 0):

When we say it's the best buffer, we mean that the solution can resist pH change in either direction, and this occurs when $\ce{pH=pK_a}$. In the Henderson-Hasselbatch equation, $\ce{pH = pK_a + log\frac{[base]}{[acid]}}$, this is achieved as long as [base] = [acid]. The actual amounts of the acid and base forms, however, determines *how far* it can resist pH change.